# Can I use something from another series in my own?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, publishing, book, plagiarism

I’ve been working on my series for two and a half years now, and this is just now coming to my attention. My series has to do with vampires and other supernatural entities, and I’ve been using the weed Verbena as a deadly substance to vampires, but I remember that vervain, another name for it, was used for the same thing in the Netflix show and books, The Vampire Diaries. Would it be considered plagiarism and could I get into trouble for using verbena in my series? I’m into book 4 of this series and I didn’t think of this until just a couple of hours ago

Comment: Are you asking about legal trouble, or upsetting-fans trouble? Vervain has been ascribed mythical powers for millennia, but extending it to vampire-repelling does appear to be an invention of the Vampire Diaries (https://naturesgrace.co.uk/873/). But personally I wouldn't worry about borrowing the idea. But there's always garlic, if you want something else. Or find a herb of your own.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on a lot of things:

- How much you use: A school that teaches magic is fine. A school in a castle in rural Scotland that teaches magic to children in secret, starting from age 11, is going to look like plagiarism, regardless of what copyright law has to say about it.

  - Never exactly copy or closely paraphrase any text, unless it's both very short and recognizably cliché (e.g. "[It was a dark and stormy night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_was_a_dark_and_stormy_night)").
  - Never use anyone else's illustrations without permission, even if you edited them in some way.
  - Strictly speaking, nobody can [own ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idea%E2%80%93expression_distinction). If you wrote everything from scratch, and didn't copy or closely paraphrase any of the original text, then you *probably* aren't guilty of copyright infringement from a legal perspective. However, plagiarism isn't the same thing as copyright infringement. If the public perceives your writing to be unoriginal, that's a serious problem regardless of whether you can get sued over it.
- How well-established it is for the genre: Garlic repelling vampires is standard, and nobody owns that. Verbena is less standard, but it does have [established mythological uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbena#In_culture) and at least makes logical sense. If some other story has a complicated system of different herbs having different properties, in which vampires are repelled by something arbitrary, such as mustard or cinnamon, then reusing that exact herb in your story might give readers pause.

  - It can help to provide some sort of justification for why the herb functions as it does, which should ideally connect back with other thematic elements of your story (elements which are not present in the other story, hopefully).
  - I would also suggest that you avoid using similar terminology to the other story. If they call it vervain, and you can reasonably call it verbena instead, then it's probably a good idea to do so. This won't really help all that much, but it can at least discourage readers from making snap judgments.
- Whether all the similar elements come from the same place: If you borrow an idea from here, another idea from there, etc., and meld them together into something new and different, then it's likely to come across as reasonably original, provided it's well-structured and has coherent themes and worldbuilding. But if you borrow a lot of ideas from a single source, readers are more likely to pick up on that.